# ¿Cómo puedo programar una aplicación de escritorio que controle el ancho de banda de una red?

Tags: networking

quisiera alguna ayuda sobre este tema, la verdad no tengo ni la más mínima remota idea de por donde empezar, en qué lenguaje, nada

Lo que quiero hacer es una aplicación de escritorio que controle el ancho de banda de mi red wifi, con fines personales
Pero la verdad no tengo idea de como, si alguien sabe del tema y me puede mandar información  para leer sobre ello, lo agradecería mucho !

Gracias amigos !

Comment: ¿Para qué necesitas limitar el ancho de banda? ¿Para realizar respaldos a través de ssh, ftp,sftp, etc.? Podrías usar [https://www.netlimiter.com/] para limitar el ancho de banda.

Comment: Necesito aprender a hacerlo, es para un trabajo que me pidieron, pero la verdad no tengo idea de como empezar

Sé que hay programas que lo hacen ya, pero tengo que es aprender a hacerlo :/

Comment: Puedes usar Batch Windows. Existen comandos de red que te pueden servir para programar tu aplicación.
Ejemplos.
PING -> Probar conexión de red, enviando y recibiendo paquetes.
ARP -> Optimizar rendimiento de red.
TRACERT -> Seguimiento de la ruta de un paquete entre un equipo y otro en la red.
NETSTAT -> Estadística protocolos  y conexiones de red.
PATHPING -> Combinación entre PING y TRACERT.

O si lo prefieres puedes usar PowerShell.

Comment: Limitar el ancho de banda puede servirte para cuando estas realizando (o alguien más dentro de tu red) algún backcup de archivos/directorios. No sé cual sea tu objetivo.

Comment: Lo que necesito es HACER, PROGRAMAR una aplicación que limite el ancho de banda, no usar las herramientas ya hechas de Windows o de Linux o de lo que sea, necesito es PROGRAMARLA !